# Need tips for debugging Cocoa bindings

Tags: xcode, cocoa, binding, xcode4, nib

I'm encountering my second problem in three days where an errant binding is causing me hours of searching and headaches.

A glance at the stack trace indicates a problem with debugging (e.g., one of the last methods called before the runtime started generating an exception was bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:). However, I'm finding it impossible to determine WHICH binding is causing the problem:

- Nothing in the stack trace or variable inspection indicates which views were involved in the call that crashed.
- The last non-machine instruction that's traceable by stepping through code is a call to a monolithic function (awakeFromNib or makeKeyAndOrderFront).
- The message in the actual exception is mystifying - e.g., "Cannot create NSArray from object  of class NSScrollView," while creating a window that doesn't have any NSScrollViews (just two buttons and two text fields).

So... any tips for debugging these types of problems? For example:

- Is there any way to get a list of ALL of the bindings specified in a nib/xib? (The inability to do this drives me CRAZY!)
- Is there any way to find out which views or controls were involved in the crash?
- Is there any way to get more information about what's happening inside monolithic calls like awakeFromNib?

Comment: have you tried breaking on all thrown exceptions?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't seem to change the debugging output.

I think that Xcode *is* breaking when the exception is thrown - it's just that the code throwing it is, like, nine layers deep in the NIB loading / binding mechanism - and a lot of that deep API code is compiled, machine-language code operating on nondescript memory references.

Comment: alright. i have expanded on the answer below. hope it is of some use.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the xib file as source code (not in IB) and search for `"IBBindingConnection"` sections.

Example: Justin's way to search (see comments):

```
grep -A 18 -B 1 -H -a -n "IBBindingConnection" /PATH/TO/NIB
```

Comment: Not quite what I'd hoped for, but a useful tool. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidStein `grep -A 18 -B 1 -H -a -n "IBBindingConnection" /PATH/TO/NIB` or you can just use grep to search an directory.

Comment: That's somewhat better. Probably the best tip I expect to find or receive for this issue. Thanks, Justin.